# The apache2 configtest failed while while restarting apache2 service

Tags: apache2

I got this error when I re-start apache2 service. How can I resolve this issue?

```
# service apache2 restart
 * Restarting web server apache2                                                                                                                                                                   [fail] 
 * The apache2 configtest failed.
Output of config test was:
apache2: Syntax error on line 140 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mod_R.load: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_R.so into server: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_R.so: undefined symbol: ap_log_rerror
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

Comment: What's on line 140 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with error:

```
apache2: Syntax error on line 140 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax 
error on line 2 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php7.0.load ...
```

I checked **/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php7.0.load** and at line 2 it had:

```
LoadModule php7_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.0.so
```

But in my **/usr/lib/apache2/modules** folder I had a newer module:

```
libphp7.2.so
```

So In **/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php7.0.load** I changed it to:

```
LoadModule php7_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.2.so
```

when I run configtest again, it shows result:

```
[Fri Jul 27 06:12:19.100729 2018] [so:warn] [pid 12179] AH01574: 
module php7_module is already loaded, skipping
```

So it works for me.

([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49439812/apache-not-starting-in-linux-mint))